# Finding the free busy of a user using google calendar API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

I want to get the busy slots of a user based on his google calendar.

```
calendar.freebusy.query({
                resource: {
                    timeMin: startTime,
                    timeMax: endTime,
                    timeZone: timeZone,
                    items: [{ id: userEmail }],
                },
            })
```

**userEmail**: The user whose busy slots I want to find out.
But, After using this function, Getting the error:

> [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound' } ]

Note: I have used some another email ID for the configuration of google calendar OAuth.

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that error in two different ways:

1. the calendar you want to query does not exist
2. your credentials (API key or OAuth token) do not have access that calendar

So if you are sure "userEmail" matches an existing calendar, you need to make it public (if you have access to it) or get an OAuth token that has access to that calendar (e.g. provided by the owner of the calendar).

[This](https://docs.simplecalendar.io/find-google-calendar-id/) is a useful resource about how to retrieve calendarIDs.